# Print all possible strings in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to make a functions that prints all the possible combinations from the given string.
example:
given_string = "ABC"
this should print:
AAA
AAB
AAC
ABA
ABB
ABC
..
and so on, until it reaches maximum options.
CCC

I found some code on the web and modified it for JS

```js
s = ["A", "B", "C"]

function printAllKLength(set, k) {
  n = set.length;
  printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k);
}

function printAllKLengthRec(set, prefix, n, k) {
  if (k == 0) {
    console.log(prefix);
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
    printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
  }
}
printAllKLength(s, 4)
```

It only changes the last character and I don't understand where is my mistake.
original code URL:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While declaring your variables, you have missed out on using the `var` keyword and especially before declaring `i` in the `for` statement. It's important since **variables without `var` keyword are defined in global scope** and each recursive call is using the same `i` variable for the `for` loop. That's the reason it generates very few possibilities. See the fixed code below:

```js
s = ["A", "B", "C"]

function printAllKLength(set, k) {
  n = set.length;
  printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k);
}

function printAllKLengthRec(set, prefix, n, k) {
  if (k == 0) {
    console.log(prefix);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // ^^^ Notice var, it scopes the variable to the function otherwise, it will be global 
    newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
    printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
  }
}
printAllKLength(s, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer already demonstrated how to fix your code.  But I just want to point out a simpler recursion to calculate these values, leaving the printing for a separate step:

```js
const allCombos = (n, xs) =>
  n == 0
    ? ['']
    : allCombos (n - 1, xs) .flatMap (c => xs. map(x => c + x))

console .log (
  allCombos (3, ['A', 'B', 'C']),
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

For `n`-character strings, we simply recur on `n - 1` characters, and for each of those, map over the characters, appending each to the string.  When `n` is `0`, we simply return an array containing the empty string.